# Debugging C++ compiler error

Tags: c++

I'm still a noobie in c++ so I am not to skilled in debugging yet. Just trying to figure out how to fix this compilation error.

> CruiseShip.cpp:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘n’

**CruiseShip.cpp**

```
#include "CruiseShip.h"
#include "Ship.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Ship s;
int passengers;

  CruiseShip(string n, string y, int p) : Ship(n,y)
  {
    passengers=p;
  }

   void print()
   {
    cout<<"Name: "<<s.getName()<<"\nMaximum passengers:"<<passengers<<endl;
  cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
   }
```

**CruiseShip.h**

```
#ifndef CRUISESHIP_H
#define CRUISESHIP_H
#include "Ship.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//class Ship;

class CruiseShip:public Ship{
    private:
        int passengers;
        Ship::Ship s;
    public:


        CruiseShip(string, string, int);

    virtual void print();
};

#endif
```

**Ship.h**

```
#ifndef SHIP_H
#define SHIP_H
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

class Ship{
private:
    string name;
    string built;

public:
    Ship();
    Ship(string, string);
    string getName();
    string getBuilt();
    virtual void print();


};
#endif
```

Comment: In CruiseShip.cpp: `CruiseShip::CruiseShip(string n, string y, int p)...`. Also, no need to re-declare `s` and `passengers` there.

Comment: `Ship::Ship s;` doesn't look to be correct.  Most likely you need `Ship s`.

Comment: And, if you are inheriting from `Ship`, do you really need the `s` member variable?

Comment: Why does CruiseShip inherit from `Ship` and contain a separate explicit instance of it?  You seem to have some confusion about composition vs inheritance going on.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 errors:

1 and 2. You don't declare `print` and `CruiseShip` (The constructor) as part of the class `CruiseShip` when you define them. You need to:

```
CruiseShip::CruiseShip(string n, string y, int p) : Ship(n,y) {
virtual void CruiseShip::print() {
```

3, you dont have a namespace `Ship` so this is unnecessary:

```
 Ship::Ship s; // This only needs to be Ship s <- NameSpace::ObjectType nameOfObject;
```

After this it will compile http://ideone.com/wJ6mPO. It will not link however, because you have undefined references to all of the functions you have yet to define.

Comment: I had _CruiseShip::CruiseShip(string n, string y, int p) : Ship(n,y)_ in my header file before and it told me I had an extra qualification of it.

Comment: @willh231 But now it is in a cpp file. You need to tell it what class it belongs to.